# best practice for making a maven parent project

Tags: java, maven

I developped a multi-module project which is a kind of java web framework.
One of the submodules is a parent pom that I provide for the users of my framework. This parent configures plugins and dependencies for them.
My problem is that this parent pom must refers the sibling modules with their version, which is ${project.version}, and because of the maven project inheritance, the ${project.version} is not the one I want.

To illustrate, my framework projects structure looks like :

```
my-framework/
|_pom.xml
|_parent/
  |_pom.xml
|_server/
  |_pom.xml
|_ui/
  |_pom.xml
```

and my parent pom looks like :

```
<project
    ....
<!-- General information -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>my-framework-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>my.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <my.framework.version>${project.version}</my.framework.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-framework-server</artifactId>
            <version>${my.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>my.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-framework-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${my.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencyManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

Then, if a user uses this parent, as maven resolves ${project.version} in the context of the user's project, ${my.framework.version} will be the user's project version instead my framework's version.

To solve this I generated the parent pom I want thanks to the maven-resources-plugin and I overrided the maven-install-plugin behaviour to install the generated pom.
My solution looks tricky and I would like if someone who faced the same problem has a better solution?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you: you want to be able to have the artefact my-framework in version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, my-framework-parent in version `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, my-framework-server in `1.0.2-SNAPSHOT` and my-framework-ui in version `1.0.3-SNAPSHOT`? Personally I think this is a bad idea that will get you in trouble sooner or later.

Comment: No, I want my-framework-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to refer my-framework-server 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and my-framework-ui 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. They are all sub modules of the same multi module project called my-framework.
And the goal is that my user just have to inherit my-framework-parent to get the right dependencies.

Comment: Hm..Than i don't understand your problem either...I had assumed the same as @hotzst based on your question...and the description of maven-resources-plugin/maven-install-plugin sounds wrong to me...But best is you would show a complete example (may be just with two childs and your parent pom and parent pom you want to distribute)...

Comment: You do not need to define a property for a custom version string, you can use `project.version` that one gets propagated to the child modules if you do not specify a different version. You only have to define it in the dependency management.

Comment: If I use ${project.version}, then the user's project that inherits my-framework-parent won't have the right dependencies.
Indeed, maven will resolve ${project.version} in the context of the user's project. So if the user's project version is 4.0.0, maven will try to load my-framework-server 4.0.0, and not 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: The best solution - do NOT distribute your parent pom. If you actually need similar solution - create archetype (as other frameworks do).

Comment: and what does the archetype do? if it creates a automatically the dependencymanagement and plugin definitions, that means this configuration will be repeated in every projects using my framework. If then my parent changes, then those projects will have to repeat my change. Maven is made to write things only once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution thanks to the [flatten-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/).
But I had to post a pull request to support the pluginManagement section.
https://github.com/mojohaus/flatten-maven-plugin/pull/10

So the solution was to modify my parent pom thanks to this plugin before publishing it. As a result I can set the version I want instead of using ${project.version}.